# Using shared memory in C

Tags: c, client-server, shared-memory

I would like to create a server-client program in which the two processes pass information between each other using shared memory

information to be passed:

```
typedef struct shared_mem{
int board[BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE];
int goal;
}shared_mem;
shared_mem *msg;
```

server:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int shmid;
key_t key=ftok("2048_client", 42);
if(key == -1) {
        printf("ftok failed");
        return -1;
    }


shared_mem *shm;
msg=(shared_mem *)malloc(sizeof(shared_mem));

/*
     * Create the segment
    */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(msg), IPC_CREAT)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
    * Now we attach the segment to our data space.
    */
  if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

msg=shm;

(*msg).goal=64;
}
```

client:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int shmid;
key_t key=ftok("2048_client", 42);
if(key == -1) {
        printf("ftok failed");
        return -1;
    }
shared_mem *shm;
msg=(shared_mem *)malloc(sizeof(shared_mem));
/*
     * Create the segment.
    */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(msg), 0)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
    * Now we attach the segment to our data space.
    */
  if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

msg=shm;
printf("dscsadc:  %d",msg->goal);
   }
```

I am new to shared memory and i would like to understand why it doesn't work and how it is supposed to work. I am getting "shmat: Permission denied"

Comment: How doesn't it work ? What errors do you get ?

Comment: The only things that seem obviously wrong here are that you have to supply a value for `key` ([`ftok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftok) may help with that), and you *may* also be required to round `sizeof(msg)` up to a multiple of [`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf).  Beyond that: what is this doing that you did not expect it to do?

Comment: @Zack I tried using ftok but i get the error: shmat: Permission denied

Comment: In the server, the line `msg=shm;` leaks the carefully allocated memory; remove the `malloc()` line.  Similarly in the client.

The line `(*msg).goal=64;` would conventionally be written `msg->goal = 64;` — the `->` operator was invented for a reason.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried doing that but I get an error saying every function is defined more than once:2048.c:120:40: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccNMeNPm.o: In function `main':
2048.c:(.text+0x45): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccLsff3I.o:2048_client.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
2048: In function `move_board':
(.text+0xaff): multiple definition of `move_board'
/tmp/ccNMeNPm.o:2048.c:(.text+0xa1b): first defined here And so on for all the other functions.

Comment: The linking errors are indicative of a problem with either functions being in the wrong files or the wrong files being linked to make a program.  They're unrelated to whether you can attach to shared memory.  You seem to have three files: 2048.c, 2048_client.c and (by inference) 2048_server.c (but maybe 2048.c is the server code).  You should not be linking two files containing `main()` into a single executable; it doesn't work.  Your `printf()` should end with a newline, but that too isn't your problem.

Comment: Also, assuming the first paragraph of code is from a header, you should not be defining (even tentatively) the `shared_mem *msg;` — you should only declare it: `extern shared_mem *msg;`, and then define it in each file that uses it.  See MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) (two names for the same thing) for how to make it easier for people to help you.  It's not hard to fix up your code, but it is work we shouldn't have to do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create the shared memory segment with 0000 permissions, so no-one can read or write it.

Change the `shmget()` call from:

```
if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(msg), IPC_CREAT)) < 0) {
```

to:

```
if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(msg), IPC_CREAT|0600)) < 0) {
```

Only the user running the program can access the shared memory that is created.

Note that POSIX [`shmget()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html)
says:

> - The low-order nine bits of `shm_perm.mode` are set to the low-order nine bits of `shmflg`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not limited to C only, look at the boost library. It enables you to create shared memory segments for interprocess communication.

```
using boost::interprocess;
shared_memory_object shm_obj
   (create_only,                  //only create
   "shared_memory",              //name
   read_write                   //read-write mode
   );
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html

Other then that, you can always use pipes, or if you're thinking about windows - COM.

Comment: I am limited to C only and not allowed to use Pipes and I am really trying to understand shared memory.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be more help then